# Dynamically create serializer based on model field value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like so:

```
class A:
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeignKey('SomeModel', null=True, blank=True)
```

When I serialize this, I would like the serielizer to have different formats based on whether the 'group' field is blank or not. Of course this can be achieved by having different serializers for different formats and calling them as required in the View layer:

```
class TypeASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class TypeBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'group')
```

But I wanted to handle it in the serializer layer itself and have a single serializer for this. Is that possible?

Comment: You can declare every field as SerializerMethodField and according to your condition return value or `None`.

Comment: @vishes_shell It would be better if you could write the answer so that there is no confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the get_fields methods of serializer

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   group = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
      model = A
      fields = ('id', 'name', 'group')

   def get_fields(self):
      fields = super().get_fields()
      # delete all the unnecessary fields according to your logic.
      if self.instance.group:  # if this is detials view other wise pass object in context
         del fields['group']
      return fields
```

Comment: How do you use values from the object instance in get_fields? It would be more helpful if you also wrote how you deleted the fields and include the logic.

Comment: please check, i have mention one conditions.

Comment: Yes, but it is not the condition I have stated in the question. Also, you still haven't used the object instance which I what I need to know. The condition for deleting the group field is to check if the group field of that particular instance is None or not. Could you please show how to do that?

Comment: Also, I think it should be: fields = super(YourSerializer, self).get_fields()

Comment: you can pass the object instance in serializer context from the view, then you can access it in serializer or if you pass the instance in serializer than you can access from self.instance

Comment: @RahulSarma it depends on your python version for python 3 super().get_fields() it's right. You are right for python 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184997/discussion-between-aman-kumar-and-rahul-sarma).

Answer (score 2):

`Serializer.instance` may be `None` in some cases.

And `get_fields()` is called only once because `Serializer.fields` is cached from django-rest-framework 3.10: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/commit/7232586c7caf66f20f56b36f1c6a9c9648eb94a4

In other words, when a serializer is used as a list by `many=True` (in `ListModelMixin`, or as a field of another serializer), the fields of all items in the list are determined by the first instance.

In that case, the solution is to override `to_representation()`:

```
class TypeASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'group')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        if not instance.group:
            del ret['group']
        return ret
```

This solution is a little inefficient because all fields and values are obtained from `super().to_presentation()` but some of them are removed again. You can consider fully implementing `to_representation()` without calling super's.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare every field of your serializer as `SerializerMethodField` as follows:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    group = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'group')

    def id(self, obj):
        if yourcondition(obj.group):
            return obj.id
        return another_value
    ...
```

Comment: But won't this still include 'group' as a field? Could you complete the solution and include the condition which i mentioned in the question?